# Trouble with Carbons [start/end]OfWeek in Arrays

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a weird problem. I somehow can't use the above function in an array, but just see my source code:

```php
public function getDeploymentHours($refDate = NULL)
{
        if(empty($refDate)){
            $refDate = Carbon::now();
        } else {
            $refDate = new Carbon($refDate);
        }

        echo $refDate->startOfWeek();                   
        // outputs: 2015-03-16 00:00:00

        echo "<br>";
        echo $refDate->endOfWeek();                 
        // outputs:  2015-03-22 23:59:59

        $a = [$refDate->startOfWeek(),
                    $refDate->endOfWeek()];
        print_r($a);                                    

        // outputs: Array
        //(
        //    [0] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        //        (
        //            [date] => 2015-03-22 23:59:59
        //            [timezone_type] => 3
        //            [timezone] => UTC
        //        )
        //    [1] => Carbon\Carbon Object
        //        (
        //            [date] => 2015-03-22 23:59:59
        //            [timezone_type] => 3
        //            [timezone] => UTC
        //        )
        //)
}
```

I find that very weird. Can someone imagine how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of two reasons.

#### 1. Carbon modifies itself.

When you call `startOfWeek()`, `$refDate` actually changes. Not only do you get the new date returned but the changes are set to the actual carbon object so when you could as well do this:

```
$refDate->startOfWeek();
echo $refDate;
```

and would get the same result...

#### 2. Carbon returns itself.

Most of Carbons functions actually return the object itself. For example if we track down `startOfWeek()` it ends up at `startOfDay()` which looks like this:

```
public function startOfDay()
{
    return $this->hour(0)->minute(0)->second(0);
}
```

So after all it returns the result of `second(0)`. Which is...

```
public function second($value)
{
    $this->second = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

`$this`!! So Carbon returns itself.

#### Conclusion

Because the methods actually change `$refDate` and the methods return itself you dump the exact same object twice.

#### Fix

You can simply `clone` the object instance to have two separate Carbon objects:

```
$refDate2 = clone $refDate;

$a = [$refDate->startOfWeek(),
      $refDate2->endOfWeek()];
print_r($a);
```